# yarn won't update itself

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, nvm

I cannot explain why - even if I update it - yarn keeps on staying on this buggy v1.6.0.

I have installed yarn via npm and node is installed via nvm in MacOS.

```
sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ yarn -v
1.6.0

sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ grep yarn package.json
    "yarn": "^1.7.0"

sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ which yarn
/Users/sscarduzio/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/yarn


sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ node -v
v8.11.1

sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ npm upgrade --global  yarn

sscarduzio@hilbert:/me $ yarn -v
1.6.0  <--- WTF??
```

I have ran out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved this after removing yarn.lock and package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

Solved this after removing `.yarnrc.yml` from `C:\Users\<user>` on Windows